# Left a 10 pound cryovac wrapped frozen ribeye in garage for 3 hours - is it safe to eat?

Tags: food-safety, meat

I purchased a 10 lb sleeve of ribeye from a friend who works at a sausage factory. It was purchased within an hour of it being brought back from the sausage factory and it was frozen solid.  Got busy with other things when I got home and did not remember to take it out of the car & put in the fridge for three hours.  For three hours.  It's Georgia, so likely the temperature in the closed garage was around 80°  In the evening  – when I took the meat out of the car it was still frozen in the middle, but thawed everywhere else,  but still felt cold. Is it safe to cook and consume? Thanks!

Comment: Nobody can tell you that it is safe. However, I would eat *and serve* that roast without hesitation. The 2 hour rule is ultra-uber conservative here. This question is likely to be closed as a duplicate. If it is closed, you will be led to an answer that is quite cautious. Cook it ASAP, keeping it refrigerated in the meantime, and don't serve it to anyone immuno-compromised.

Comment: Actually, I'm going to close this as a duplicate. You have the best answer I can give, and our canonical answer to the question.

Comment: And, welcome to Seasoned Advice! :)